# How to edit Page-break styles in Joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5

For those of you that know Joomla CMS (v2.5)!

As shown in the screenshot below, I have an article which displays its table of contents (article index) in a box on the right (the default style for pagebreaks).

I want to mirror this box onto the left side of the article to use it as an advert position.  Preferably, I want to make an Alternative Article Layout, and select it from the article parameters on articles I want it to show up on.

I can't locate the file though.  The article layout is found in `components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php` and the Article Index is supposed to be located in `components/com_content/view/article/tmpl/pagebreak.php` but I cant find this file.

Can anyone advise on where to find this code??

And if you know of a tutorial on creating templates, please pass it on.  I've found this http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_2.5 but haven't tried it out yet.

[image]

Comment: are you sure the Article Index isn't a module?

Comment: Yes Im sure. The index appears embedded in the content area of the layout. If you don't know that then you've obviously never used before? The above screenshot only has one module position on the right. Everything else is within the article